# Shopify Custom Message In Order Confirmation Email Based On Product Title

Tags: shopify

I am trying to add a custom message in my Shopify order confirmation emails, based on any product titles. So if a customer orders any product that contains the title "Printed", it should show some some specific content.

I have the below code, however if multiple products contain the same title "Printed", the content duplicates. I need it to not duplicate, but instead if any of the products contain the title "Printed" then it shows my content.

`{% for line in subtotal_line_items %}`
`{% if line.product.title %}`    
`{% assign line_title2 = line.product.title %}`  
`{% if line_title2 contains 'Printed' %}`
`CONTENT`
`{% else %}`
`CONTENT2`
`{% endif %}`
 `{% endif %}`
`{% endfor %}`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like this custom logic to check it, and make sure it comes in condition once. so the duplicate content is not included in the email template.

```
{% assign first_time = true %}
{% for line in subtotal_line_items %}
   {% if line.product.title  contains 'Printed' %}
     {% if first-time %}
         {{ custom title goes here }}
     {% endif %}
     {% assign first_time = false %}
   {% else %}
     {{ line.product.title }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks so much for the response, that works a treat!