# Shopify Custom Message In Order Confirmation Email Based On Product Tag or Collection

Tags: shopify

Similar to this post - [Shopify Custom Message In Order Confirmation Email Based On Product Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518685/shopify-custom-message-in-order-confirmation-email-based-on-product-title) - except only display a message if the order contains a product using a specific product tag or collection (either one will work for my purpose).

So if the customer's order contains a product that uses the tag "trailer," then the order confirmation email will display the message - just once - not for each item.

Answer provided in similar question:

```
{% assign first_time = true %}
{% for line in subtotal_line_items %}
   {% if line.product.title  contains 'Printed' %}
     {% if first-time %}
         {{ custom title goes here }}
     {% endif %}
     {% assign first_time = false %}
   {% else %}
     {{ line.product.title }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```